# Software to create exoplanet transit lightcurves of all stars in a series of images?

Tags: exoplanet, software, transits-other-than-sun

There is quite a bit software out there that can be used for the transit method analysis of single stars, is there software that can do it for many simultaneously?

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify: Are you looking for software that will measure the brightness of everything in the series of images (photometry) and build lightcurves of everything or software that will detect or analyze transits in a whole series of lightcurves (such as a whole TESS field) ? I fear the answer is "no" in both cases but it will help the answer and pointers for what software to look at as part of the solution if you can clarify what you're looking for

Comment: Do you know your reference stars?